# Need to change colour based on data. My class:getColor() is not working correct

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In datatable there are two column status and priority. STATUS LIST are OPEN or CLOSED and PRIORITY LIST are HIGH,MODERATE and LOW.So, if status is open it should be in red colour, closed then green and in priority column if priority is high then darkblue,Low - warning colour and Moderate- info colour.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

For Status column colours are getting displayed but for priority column is not working.

HTML templete -

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="searchFilterArray"
  disable-pagination
  :hide-default-footer="true"
>
           
    <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
      <span :class="getColor(item.status)">
        {{ item.status }} // status can be open or closed
      </span>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.priority="{ item }">
      <span :class="getColor(item.priority)">
        {{ item.priority }} // priority can be High,Moderate or Low
      </span>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```
 methods: {
    getColor (status) {
      console.log('status is : ', status) // In console only open and closed are getting printed. Not sure why Low and High are not going as per screenshot.
      if (status === 'closed') return 'v-green font-weight-bold'
      else if (status === 'open') return 'v-error font-weight-bold'
      else if (status === 'High') return 'v-darkblue font-weight-bold'
      else if (status === 'Low') return 'v-warning font-weight-bold'
      else if (status === 'Moderate') return 'v-info font-weight-bold'
      else return 'v-secondary '
    },
 }
```

Comment: You can pass an object to :class, with true/false as values

Comment: @kiran it looks like a data issue, console should printed `priority` if you are having any property name `priority` in your item object. Hence, can you please verify and check

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I have attached screenshot on the list searchFilterArray as well.

Comment: @kiran You are passing `item.priority` in `getColor` method, it should be `item.priority.name` as priority is an object.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I changed my code to  `<template v-slot:item.priority="{ item }">
              <span :class="getColor(item.priority.name)">
                {{ item.priority }}
              </span>
            </template>` but no change

Comment: Are you getting the value in console now ? for priority ?

Comment: Not yet. In console "status is :  open" this is only getting printed.

Comment: @kiran it's `v-slot:item.priority.name`, your slot is not used because it does not match, and that's why there is no console.log

Comment: @Lk77 Correct. Thank you so much. Issue is resolved. I made below changes `<template v-slot:item.priority.name="{ item }">
              <span :class="getColor(item.priority.name)">
                {{ item.priority.name }}
              </span>
            </template>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an object, with your conditions in it :

```
getColor (status) {
    return {
      'v-green font-weight-bold': status === 'closed',
      'v-error font-weight-bold': status === 'open',
      'v-darkblue font-weight-bold': status === 'High',
      'v-warning font-weight-bold': status === 'Low',
      'v-info font-weight-bold': status === 'Moderate',
      // You perhaps need to be more specific with this one 
      // for example with a 
      // !['closed', 'open', 'High', 'Low', 'Moderate'].includes(status)
      'v-secondary': !status
    }
}
```

you don't need to have a if/else and return the correct classes yourself, vue will figure out which classes to put depending on the boolean value

---

However i don't think it's your issue, because it's seems your console.log does not output those values so your method is not called, perhaps a slot issue, is your slot actually used ?

Perhaps your column is not actually called priority and it does not work, even if your header says it's the priority column, the actual field on the object could be something else like order

---

If your field is actually `priority.name` you need to change your template :

```html
<template v-slot:item.priority.name="{ item }">
  <span :class="getColor(item.priority.name)">
    {{ item.priority.name }} // priority can be High,Moderate or Low
  </span>
</template>
```

What is happenning currently is that your slot does not match the field and is not called by vuetify.

Comment: To send value to datatable is am using { text: 'Priority', value: 'priority.name', sortable: true },

Comment: @kiran i think that's why, your value is actually `item.priority.name`, also your item might be different from the data you provided initially, i don't know vuetify so i can't tell, try to console.log(item)

Comment: Thank you for your support. Issue is resolved. I tried to console.log(item) and then I got exact issue